# How to find how many weeks in a current month based on Todays Date and what are the dates in each week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing an application for my Organization. I need to find out how many weeks in current month based on Today's date and what are the dates in each week

Eg: If logged in application Today i.e. 25-Dec-2020, then I need to find out how many weeks in December and what are the dates in each week.

[Please refer attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goE32.png)

Comment: Its clear what you want to accomplish. But its not clear what research you have done, what options you have considered, and where you got stuck?

Comment: i can able to find out the week number based on current date. But i want total weeks in a week and what are the dates in each week. 

declare @date as datetime = '2021-12-25'
select DATEPART(week,@date) - DATEPART(week,cast(cast(year(@date) as varchar(4))+'-' + cast(month(@date) as varchar(2)) + '-01' as datetime))+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... You will get TotalWeeks, WeekNo, Dates fall in each week. Change it further as you need

```
DECLARE @Today DATE, @Year INT, @Month INT, @Start INT=1, @MaxDate DATETIME, @Days INT, @CDate DATE, @Week INT=1

SET @Today='2020-11-25'

SELECT @MaxDate = DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(@Today),DATEADD(MONTH,1,@Today))
SELECT @Days = DAY(@MaxDate)

DECLARE @WeekS TABLE(Dat Date,WeekNo INT, WeekName VARCHAR(20))

SELECT @Year =YEAR(@Today), @Month =MONTH(@Today)

WHILE(@Start <=@Days)
BEGIN
    SET @CDate = CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(@Start AS VARCHAR(2))

    INSERT @WeekS
    SELECT @CDate, @Week, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @CDate)
    
    IF (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @CDate) ='Saturday')
        SET @Week = @Week +1
        
    SELECT @Start = @Start +1
END

SELECT Distinct Max(WeekNo) Over() TotalWeeks ,  WeekNo,  Dat FROM @WeekS
```

Comment: Thank You !! your query is returning what I'm expecting. But i need more affective as follows.

Week   Date
1          01-Dec-2020
1           02-Dec-2020
1          03-Dec-2020
..
..

Comment: Script Updated! Please check now

Comment: i got it but dates should be 01-Dec-2020, 02-Dec-2020,03-Dec-2020....

Comment: You can change it in final select statement (i.e: Format(Dat,'dd-MMM-yyyy'))

Comment: Perfect query....need small correction i.e. you treated week as Monday to Sunday but week should be Sunday to Saturday

Comment: Changed accordingly. Try now